# Joins in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I have two tables:

- table A (ID, Name, Link, Type, CID)
- table B (ID, Name, Link, ImagePath, Price, CID)

The problem I have is I want to join these two tables on base of ID

```
ID       Name     Type         CID
1        Apple    Category     0
2        TV       Category     0
3        Laptop   Category     0
```

In the same table A, the ID of apple tv and laptop is being passed to sub category as CID

```
ID      Name      Type               CID
4       Macbook   sub category       1
5       iTV       sub category       2
6       HP        sub category       3
```

ID of category is in sub category as CID in same table. ID of sub category will be passed to child category in the same table as CID

```
ID       Name        Type                CID
7        Applebook   Child category      4
8        TV MLT2     child category      5
9        HP Mini     Child Category      6
```

The ID of child category will be passed to table B as CID which is 7 8 and 9.

How can I join these tables now that I should search APPLE I should have all the products of apple from table a and B both. What should I do to join table A with B on base of ID then child category with sub category on base of ID and CID then with main category. What join should I use?

I understand joins well almost I guess left right inner outer but I don't know what should I do in my case? How can I join my category with sub then sub with child then child with table B on base of ID which becomes CID in other

Comment: You should edit your question to contain your actual tables & data and a clear example of what you want as the output.

Comment: Please show the expected output for category 'Apple'.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use normal joins several times:

```
select 
    C.*
from
    yourtable a
    join yourtable b on a.ID = b.CID
    join yourtable c on b.ID = c.CID
where 
    a.name = 'Apple'
```

Comment: If there may be arbitrary levels of depth in the categories, you want a recursive CTE.

Comment: it's confusing for me because i have products in 'category' which has ID and those 'categories' has 'sun categories' and has CID from ID, and ID of sub categories is being passed to child categories as CID and ID of those child categories is being passed to another table as CID now i want all data of apple and other categories as well with joins i just understand basic joins i don't know what to do in this situation

Comment: @jamesZ join is working i guess or i am not fully understand yet, i think it will be a path from table B to A in child categories then from child to sub then from sub to main categories, for that what will i have to do?

Comment: The same table is joined several times for this "path". No idea what your actual problem is. Like @RossPresser said, if it's not just 3 deep all the time, you'll need a recursive CTE.

Comment: actually i have 14 categories only then sub then child then their data in another table and @RossPresser and JamesZ i am building stored procedures for every category as u can say 14 procedure where i will have to use use for every category and have their data to be shown through stored procedures, and please tell me how to use  multiple joins

Comment: i can join child category with another table which has CID but then i can't connect or join that with upper sub category

Comment: Yes that should be just fine, doesn't matter if it's the same table or not. Not sure if you need someone to help you or just someone that speaks your language...